# Php behaviour suddenly changed loading jquery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm building a site that uses jQuery in WP and until yesterday it has been working fine. I realized none of my jQuery files were being read. When I removed the array('jquery') where I enqueue my scripts it started working again. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Old code that worked and stopped working

```
wp_enqueue_script('themename-myfilename', get_template_directory_uri() . '/src/js/myfilename.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
```

Modified code that works (note removed array('jquery'))

```
wp_enqueue_script('themename-myfilename', get_template_directory_uri() . '/src/js/myfilename.js', null, true);
```

I don't want to risk loading it incorrectly. 
Appreciate any help!

Comment: with second variation of your code you moved your `js` file from footer to header. Do your script using jQuery library?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress installations contain jQuery, you just have to include/activate it by putting this into the `<header>` tag in the `head.php` file   (no need for your own version or similar):

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>
```